# Does there exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^{\infty}|\sin(x^{n})|$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I know that $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^{\alpha})$ converges for $|\alpha| \geq 1$ which can be attributed to cancellation of areas and $\int_0^{\infty}|\sin(x^{n})|$ diverges for $n = 2$ since there is no cancellation of areas. It seems unlikely but is there a $n$ such that the area of the oscillations can be made so small that it can be approximated by a geometric series and hence show that this integral converges?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Consider $\int^A_1|\sin(t^n)|\,dt$. Then
$$\int^A_1|\sin(t^n)|\,dt=\int^A_1\frac{|\sin(t^n)|}{t^n} t^n\,dt=
\frac{1}{n}\int^{A^n}_1\frac{|\sin u|}{|u|} u^{1/n}du\geq \frac{1}{n}\int^{A^n}_1\frac{|\sin u|}{|u|}du\rightarrow\infty$$
as $A\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 0):

You have $$ \int_0^\infty |\sin(x^n)| dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$$
where \begin{align} a_k &= \int_{\sqrt[n]{k\pi}}^{\sqrt[n]{(k+1)\pi}} |\sin(x^n)|dx =^{x=y^{\frac1n}} \\
&= \int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi} |\sin y| \frac{y^{\frac1n-1}}{n}dy \ge \\
&\ge \int_{k\pi}^{k\pi+\pi} |\sin y| \frac{(k\pi+\pi)^{\frac1n-1}}{n}dy = \\
&= 2\frac{\pi^{\frac1n-1}}{n} (k+1)^{\frac1n-1}\end{align}

By comparison test, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is divergent.